# One `Select` query to generate 12 result sets

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table called VAT, and I need to generate the monthly VAT report. So below is what I do...

```
    SELECT SUM(Amount) AS "January" 
    WHERE current_time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-310'
    FROM VAT
```

Just like the above query, I have 12 queries for January, February, March etc. So, instead of writing 12, is there a way that I can get all of these in 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional sum with case statement,below query will give you one row with 12 columns as for each month's sum

```
SELECT 
   SUM(case when current_time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31' then Amount else 0 end) AS `January` ,
   SUM(case when current_time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-29' then Amount else 0 end) AS `Febuary` ,
   .
   .
   .
   SUM(case when current_time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-31' then Amount else 0 end) AS `December` 
 FROM VAT
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY`, like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount), MONTH(current_time_stamp) AS `Month` 
FROM VAT
WHERE current_time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(current_time_stamp)
```

However, it could be slow in case you have a lot of records.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that expanding to twelve months

```
SELECT MAX(X.January) AS January, MAX(X.February) AS February FROM
(
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS January, 0 AS February
    WHERE current_time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
    FROM VAT
UNION
SELECT 0 AS January, SUM(Amount) AS February
    WHERE current_time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-29'
    FROM VAT
) X
```

Or you also can do that:

```
SELECT 'January' AS Month, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    WHERE current_time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
    FROM VAT
UNION
 SELECT 'February' AS Month, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    WHERE current_time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-29'
    FROM VAT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.mnth_amt,t.mnth 
from (
     select sum(amount) as mnth_amt,MONTH(current_time_stamp ) as mnth from vat where current_time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND  
     '2014-12-31' GROUP BY MONTH(current_time_stamp) 
     ) t order by mnth
```